# 2 different Firestore interfaces

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've got 2 different firestore interfaces: both using the same firestore project.

[image]

[image]

I'm finding this abit confusing - which one am I meant to operate in?

How come the 2nd doesn't have access to other settings such as Rules?

Answer (score 3):

They are both meant for you to operate in.  Which one you use depends on whatever your preference is.  If you prefer to stay in the Firebase ecosystem, then use the Firebase console.  If you prefer to stay in the Google Cloud ecosystem, then use the Cloud console.

Read more about the [differences with Cloud Firestore between Firebase and Google Cloud](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e).

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore is available with, or without Firebase SDKs.

For Firebase users, the Firebase interface allows you to configure Firebase specific functionality (Rules).

For GCP users, the Google Cloud interface keeps you closer to other services and admin settings you'll likely be using, such as IAM, BigQuery, etc. It also gives you quick access to a shell (Just click the Cloud Shell icon) so you can quickly run commands like `gcloud firestore export`.

Both interfaces will show you the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Work in the first one. The second one is a simplified screen I think, because it is also for other services